# How can I write an efficient for loop in pyspark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have pyspark code transforming a pyspark dataframe via function into multiple dataframes which I join later back into a single one.

A dynamic list (e.g. ranging from 5 to 100 items or more) determines how many dataframes I'll have to create and join later. As said, this list is dynamic and changes every time.

Below a code snippet, showcasing our current approach.

```
items = ['apples', 'oranges', 'nuts'] // this is dynamic!
df = XXX // reading in a DataFrame parallelized
collection = []

def func_abc(df):
    // transform df with groupby/count/mean/last/lag/...
    return df

for i in items:
    collection.append(func_abc(df)) // apply the function and collect result

// Join collected results
df = collection[0]
for c in collection[]:
    df.join(c, how='full')

df // contains now all datasets joined
```

Question here is, how can we do this more efficiently? 
We assume the loop breaks the spark lazy evaluation as `func_abc` might contain counts triggering evaluations?!

Hope this is specific enough, happy to provide clarity :)

Comment: If you're going to perform a join on _100 items or more_ for loop is the least of your concerns. Not that it really is, at least based on the information you've provided so far.

Comment: This question seems too vague to be answered -- what specific problems are you facing? Why do you need this to be optimized?

Comment: One simple optimization might be to cache df before the repeated evaluations of func_abc. This will ensure that operations on df (after the first) are performed on data that is already in memory.